# Do you know if I can sort a piechart according to slice size in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Do you know if I can sort a piechart according to slice size in Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorting piechart according to slice size is fixed and should be deliver until start of next week.